# Is $\int dx dy \frac{f(x) g(y)}{y-x + i0}$ defined on piecewise continous functions

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, quantum-field-theory, cauchy-principal-value

### Question:

Let $f,g$ be piecewise continous square-integrable functions. Then, is the following limit integral well-defined (and finite)?
$$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int dx dy ~ \frac{f(x) g(y)}{y-x + i\epsilon} < \infty. $$
If not, what would be a counter-example. If so, how can this be proven?

### Thoughts and ideas:

**Differentiable functions would work:**
If $f$ and $g$ would be differentiable, existence of the above integral would be clear. I would write $1/(y-x + i\epsilon)$ as the derivative of a regular function and partially integrate. Then, the limit in $\epsilon$ can be taken without problems.

**One integral is not enough:**
I did not expect that such integrals exist because they do not exist in one variable. For example, let $s(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in (0,1) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$. Then, using Sokhotsky's formula one can show that:
$$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int dx~ \frac{s(x)}{x + i\epsilon} = -i \pi s(0) + \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^1 \frac{1}{x} = -\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \ln(\epsilon) = \infty. $$
However, it seems that another integral further regularizes the simple pole as $\epsilon \to 0$. For example, when setting $f$ and $g$ equal to $s$, the integral in question can be computed (which I did using again Sokhotsky's formula).
Again, an integral in one variable would be unproblematic for differentiable functions with sufficient fall-off behavior. Possible problems are due to the restriction to piecewise continous functions.

### Background:

In quantum field theories, so-called matrix elements of operators $A$ have distributional behavior. They have to be integrated with states from the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ to be well-defined:
$$ \langle \psi| A | \phi \rangle = \int d^m p d^n q~ \underbrace{\psi(p_1, .., p_m) \phi(q_1, .., q_n)}_{\text{states } \in \mathcal H} ~ \underbrace{\langle p_1, .., p_m| A |q_1, .., q_n\rangle}_{\text{matrix element}} < \infty $$
The Hilbert space usually contains $L^2$ function of several variables (symmetrized or anti-symmetrized for bosons and fermions, respectively). It is possible to restrict to subspace (e.g., Schwartz functions) if necessary.
One particular type of poles are *kinematic poles*, which are of the form $\frac{1}{p_i - q_j + i0}$. I am asking whether it is necessary to restrict the Hilbert space to allow for such poles.